# LaTex: start a command in the beginning of an environment and end it in the ending definition

Tags: latex, beamer

This may be dumb or obvious, but I am learning to make sty files and I have been modifying some code from the beamerposter project. Anyway, I have this:

```
\def\postercolumn#1
{\begin{column}{#1\textwidth}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
        \begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth}
            %\parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}
}

\def\endpostercolumn
{
        \end{minipage}
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{column}
}
```

Obviously the \parbox command is commented out, but I want it to start there and end in the end block. In effect, I want this:

```
\def\postercolumn#1
{\begin{column}{#1\textwidth}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
        \begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth}
            \parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{
}

\def\endpostercolumn
{
        }
        \end{minipage}
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{column}
}
```

But naturally, this doesn't work because the compiler gets confused and thinks the \endpostercolumn section is closing. Is there some obvious way to get around that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `\bgroup` and `\egroup` instead of `{` and `}`. Not sure however.

`\bgroup` is `\let` to `{`, so it's an *implicit* `{`. Thus it should not be considered as extra grouping command until getting to TeX's "stomach". The same about `\egroup`.

---

Edit: I tried it with the `\parbox`, it seems to be not working correctly (because `\parbox` seems to expand tokens too early). With `\vtop` it works:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newlength\columnheight \columnheight=5cm % needed to define \columnheight,
                                          % don't have it here

\def\postercolumn{
    \leavevmode
    \vtop to \columnheight\bgroup
    \hsize.5\textwidth
    \noindent
    \ignorespaces
}

\def\endpostercolumn{
    \egroup
}


\begin{document}

\begin{postercolumn}
   hello world hello world hello world hello world
   hello world hello world hello world hello world
\end{postercolumn}

\end{document}
```

Seems that this is what you need.

---

Edit: of course, you would need `\hsize\textwidth` instead of `\hsize.5\textwidth`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `\parbox`, you can use the `minipage` environment:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  % ...
\end{minipage}

% If you want to explicitly define the height:
\begin{minipage}[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}
  % ...
\end{minipage}
```

The `minipage` environment has the same options as the `\parbox` command:

```
\begin{minipage}[pos][height][inner-pos]{width}
  % ... text ...
\end{minipage}
```

where `pos` is one of `c`, `t`, or `b` (for center, top, and bottom, respectively); `height` is the desired height of the box, `inner-pos` is one of `c`, `t`, `b`, or `s` (for center, top, bottom, and stretch, respectively); and `width` is the desired width of the box.

If you choose `s` for the `inner-pos` value, the text be stretched to fill the vertical space in the box (extra space will be added between paragraphs).  If you choose not to specify `inner-pos`, it will be set to the same as `pos`.

I haven't tested this with your code, but it should work.  (I've used it when defining new environments before.)